# Event firing sequence for a submit button

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Say a submit button has a click event handler as well (yes, it's wrong, but that's really the code I'm working on).

And the click handler sets a value in a field of the form that's about to be submitted.

So when the submit button is clicked:

1. What will fire first, the form submit event or the click event?
2. Will the value set in the form field by the click event submitted to the server? I think this depends on the answer to Q1. If the form is posted first, I'm guessing it won't.

Note: I'm not looking for alternatives and advice. I know what the proper way of handling this will be. Just trying to understand the sequence of events and their implications.

Answer (score 5):

1. The click event on the submit button
2. Yes, events resolve before default functionality, so the event runs and then the button submits the form (firing the submit event and then actually submitting the data).

Answer (score 0):

First will be called event, there You have last chance f.ex to block form submitting. Then submit with changed values by event routine.